# Gráfico web com c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta open source para geração de gráficos com c#(MVC)? Serão gráficos em linha e barras.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/ - https://www.chartjs.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As opções abaixo são ambas *free* e fáceis de implementar:

- **Google Charts** - [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
- **Rickshaw** - [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/)
- **CanvasJS** - [CanvasJS](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/asp-net-mvc-charts/)

Coloquei em ordem em que **eu** achei mais fácil de trabalhar e implementar. Pode testar todos e ver qual você se adapta melhor.